# How can I insert multiple values in a single query using MyBatis annotations?

Tags: java, mysql, orm, annotations, mybatis

Are there any examples for inserting a collection into a Database (MySQL) using a single query using MyBatis annotations and not the XML?

I have the following query in a MyBatis DAO.

```
  @Insert("insert into deleted_items(item_id) " + "values (#{itemID})")
 int put(String itemID);
```

I want to insert a `List<String>` using the same query as above, just allow for multiple values.

How can I do that using only annotations?

Comment: What do you have so far? Please paste some example code.

Comment: edited the question with an example.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this is not possible using annotations. Not sure about xml.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can insert collection in database using MyBatis annotation 
Here is example

I have one user list and want to insert that list in database using MyBatis annotation without xml mapping

```
 @Insert({"<script>", 
        "insert into  user_master (first_name,last_name) values ",
        "<foreach collection='userList' item='user' index='index' open='(' separator = '),(' close=')' >#{user.first_name},#{user.last_name}</foreach>",
        "</script>"})
    int insertUserList(@Param("userList") List<UserNew> userList);
```

I successfully insert more then 25 record in my rest call using above insertUserList.

I hope it will helpful to you.